# Shall I use an article before the word "value"

Tags: word-usage, articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

I am not sure if the word value is countable or non-countable. So I am not sure if i should add an article before it in a context like:

> Our method adds a value over their method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Value* is countable in some contexts, but not here. The relevant meaning of [*value*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/value) from Merriam-Webster is

> 3: relative worth, utility, or importance
>
> > a good *value* at the price
> >
> > the *value* of base stealing in baseball
> >
> > had nothing of *value* to say

"Relative worth, utility, or importance" is not something that's countable.

If you were talking about a different sense of *value*, like "a numerical quantity", then you'd have a countable noun. For example: "One possible *value* of X is 20".